# angular SSR deployment in Cpanel

Tags: node.js, angular, cpanel, angular-universal

I'm trying to deploy an angular universal project on Cpanel I uploaded the file and installed it

in subdirectory public_html/aqar_front i added htaccess in public_html with the following code

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:4000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:4000/$1 [P,L]
```

then I run this command

```
npm run serve:ssr
```

it's working fine in the browser

[image]

but as you know when I closed the terminal the application stopped so I used pm2 to keep it running but it's not working in the browser 
[image]

I used this command

```
pm2 start  dist/server.js  -- --port 4000
```

but it's doesn't work from browser any help, please 
here is my angular and node js version

> Angular CLI: 8.3.4
>   Node: 12.13.1
>   OS: linux x64
>   Angular: 8.2.6

Comment: Your first screenshot shows that serve:ssr runs local.js; how did you choose to start dist/server.js with pm2.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  you saved my day thank you it's working after I run 
 pm2 start  local.js  -- --port 4000

Answer (score 0):

ok for anyone face this problem I run local.js instead of server.js

```
 pm2 start local.js -- --port 4000
```

and it's working fine now